Could not find web.cacerts while cloning HG Repository
I am using Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 6.8.1). python version 3.12 .
I am trying to clone HG repository, first i got SSL handshake error

Then i refered mercurial SecureConnections so i added [web]cacerts variable with actual path in hgrc file,
this hgrc files -

cacert.pem is available in given in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/certifi location. As you can see in below image


But i am getting this abort: could not find web.cacerts: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem error while cloning HG repository.

Could some one help on this to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.
